# C++ authentication against PHP with cURL

Tags: php, c++, curl, libcurl

Im trying to get my c++ app to authenticate user/pass against a web database. To do so, I have a simple html form for user/pass which triggers the authentication php script.

Im having a hard time understanding cURL since im a complete noob on it.
Right now, I'm able to send data to the html form, but i dont even know if im doing properly.

Ideally, I would like you to teach me how to do it, and how to read a response. I mean, if the login goes right, how do i get c++ to know it?

All the code i have:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="check.php">
    <input type="text" name="uname"/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$fileDir = '/var/www/html/forums/';
require($fileDir . '/src/XF.php');
XF::start($fileDir);
$app = \XF::setupAPP('XF\App');

$username = $_POST['uname']; $password = $_POST['password'];

$ip = $app->request->getIp();
$loginService = $app->service('XF:User\Login', $username, $ip);

$userValidate = $loginService->validate($password, $error);
if(!$userValidate)
{
    //Not good pass / user
    $data = ['validated' => false];
}
else $data = ['validated' => true];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

C++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char username[20];
char password[25];

cout << "Username: ";
cin >> username;
cout << "Password: ";
cin >> password;

/*------------------------------------------*/

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://localhost/index.hmtl");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "uname=?&password=?", username, password);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

**EDIT: WORKING SOLUTION**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

string urlencode(const string &str) {
char *escaped = curl_escape(str.c_str(), str.length());
if (escaped == NULL) throw runtime_error("curl_escape failed!");

string ret = escaped;
curl_free(escaped);
return ret;
}

size_t my_write_function(const void * indata, const size_t size, const    size_t count, void *out) {
(*(string*)out).append((const char*)indata, size*count);
return size * count;
}

int main()
{
string username;
string password;

cout << "Username: ";
getline(cin, username);
cout << "Password: ";
getline(cin, password);

/*------------------------------------------*/

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://urlto/index.html");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, string("uname=" + urlencode(username) + "&password=" + urlencode(password)).c_str());

    string response;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://urlto/check.php");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_write_function);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    //cout << "Response from website: " << response << endl;
    if (response.find("true") == string::npos) {
        cout << "Failed to login";
    }
    else cout << "Log in successful";

    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Comment: Does the C++ program work standalone?  The CURLOPT_URL looks wrong.  I would expect something like "https : //localhost/check.php"

Comment: "https://...check.php" its the censored version of it. The original one contains a full URL. So yes, the c++ works standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i dont even know if im doing properly.` - well, there's certainly a couple of bugs in your code,

first, what do you think happens if the username is longer than 20 bytes, or the password is longer than 25 bytes? try

```
string username;
getline(cin, username);
```

instead. c++ will keep increasing the size of username as needed until you run out of ram, as it should be.

and i see you're using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` (and wrongly), until you know what you're doing, i recommend you use `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` instead. (btw i pretty much always use COPYPOSTFIELDS myself) this line is wrong:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "uname=?&password=?", username, password);`
```

because curl_easy_setopt() only accepts 3 parameters, but you're trying to give it 5. i don't think that will even compile, but even if it does, it certainly shouldn't work at runtime. 
try instead something like:

```
string urlencode(const string& str)
{
    char *escaped = curl_escape(str.c_str(), str.length());
    if (unlikely(escaped==NULL))
    {
        throw runtime_error("curl_escape failed!");
    }
    string ret = escaped;
    curl_free(escaped);
    return ret;
}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, string("uname="+urlencode(username)+"&password="+urlencode(password)).c_str());
```

as for reading (and capturing) the output, there's lots of ways to do it, but how about hooking the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION? that tends to work, something like:

```
size_t my_write_function( const void * indata, const size_t size, const size_t count, void *out){
    (*(string*)out).append((const char*)indata,size*count);
    return size*count;
}
```

then

```
string response;
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,my_write_function);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,&response);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
cout << "response from website: " << response << endl;
```

now you can check if you logged in or not by check checking for the existence of the string "true" in the response (because it should respond something like `{validated:true}` if you are), eg

```
if(response.find("true")==string::npos){
    cout << "failed to authenticate!";
}else{
    cout << "authenticated successfully!";
}
```

(and a warning, while it may be tempting to use a lambda callback with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, it's a trap, c++ lambdas may crash when given to curl as callbacks... been there, done that.)

Comment: thank you for your reply! The write function you've sent me doesnt want to work, gives an error related to the ".append".

Comment: you can not perform the conversion from 'const void *' to 'const std :: basic_string <char, std :: char_traits <char>, std :: allocator <char >>

Comment: @Soul try `(*(string*)out).append((const char*)indata,size*count);`

Comment: that did the trick. I edited the question with my working solution, if you have the time, check what I did, because I think it might not be the way its supposed to. I first send the post data, then change the url again to get the response. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Soul by calling CURLOPT_URL twice without actually running curl, you're just wasting a bit of cpu, no harm done ^^ (but you can remove the first CURLOPT_URL call, it doesn't do anything)